# NullPointerException with ternary operator

Tags: java, comparison

Why does this work:

```
String a = null;
String b = a != null && a.equals("Nan") ? "Nan" : a;
System.out.println(b);
```

but this produces NPE:

```
Double value = null;
Double v = value != null && value.isNaN() ? 0.0 : value;
System.out.println(v);
```

Rewriting it as:

```
Double value = null;
Double v;
if (value != null && value.isNaN()) {
    v = 0.0;
} else {
    v = value;
}
```

of course works as expected. But why do I get NPE using the ternary/conditional operator when using `Double` and no NPE when using `String`? What am I missing?

Comment: Which line of code throws the NPE?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer The second line is the only one that can throw an NPE.  (Unless someone does something silly like `System.setOut(null);`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the conditional expression is inferred as `double`, so you get a `NullPointerException` when the program attempts to unbox `value` (which is `null`) as a primitive `double`.

To make the expression have a `Double` result (which can store `null`), cast `0.0` to `Double`.

```java
Double v = value != null && value.isNaN() ? (Double) 0.0 : value
```

See [§15.25.2. Numeric Conditional Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend the above accepted answer which is to the point but you may as well avoid casting here.

```
   Double value = null;
   Double v = value != null && value.isNaN() ? Double.valueOf(0.0) : value;
   System.out.println(v);
```

The `Double.valueOf(0.0)` will provide a `Double` in first type of condition which will make the conditional operator to evaluate into the type of `Double` since `value` is as well of type `Double`. So if no participant of condition is of primitive type `double`, it will not try any unboxing and a NPE will not be thrown.